# @font-face not working with firefox and IE

Tags: css

I have this to attach custom font into my page

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Pushkinf";
    src: url(../fonts/pushkin.ttf);
}
```

It works on Safari and Google Chrome, but doesn't work on firefox and IE. Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Please follow this link http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%40font-face

Comment: try to use its woff, and eot format

Comment: As I know, url for font-face couldn't be absolute url, so I don't know how to insert my font using jfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proper cross-browser support, you'd need to utilize multiple font formats.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Pushkinf";
  src: url('../fonts/pushkin.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/pushkin.woff') format("woff"),
       url('../fonts/pushkin.ttf') format("truetype"),
       url('../fonts/pushkin.svg#Pushkinf') format("svg");
}
```

Comment: Of course I will, the site wants me to wait for several minutes to mark your answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

First of all You need to check the format of fonts Which Supports different browser

[image]

U need to Give Like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pushkinf';
    src: url('fonts/pushkin.eot');
    src: url('fonts/pushkin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/pushkin.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/pushkin.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/pushkin.svg#pushkin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Checkout for More details about the `.eot` fornt [here](http://caniuse.com/eot)